# Python 2.7 twitter streaming api language filter

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

I am trying to use twitter streaming API and the language filter.  As suggested by the Twitter API manual (https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#language), I put the following ways and none of them work.

```
 filter(track=['keyword'],language=en)  # NameError: name 'en' is not defined

 filter(track=['keyword'],language='en') # TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'

 filter(track=['keyword'],language=['en']) # TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'

 filter(track=['keyword'],lan=en) #TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lan'

 filter(track=['keyword'],lan='en') #TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lan'

 filter(track=['keyword'],lan=['en']) #TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lan'
```

I also tried en-US instead of en. Still doesn't work.

Could you any guru enlighten?  Thanks!  The followings are the full code:

```
 #Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
 # The code is modified from the following links
 # http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/
 # Streaming API requesting parameters: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#language
 from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
 from tweepy import OAuthHandler
 from tweepy import Stream

 #Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API (removed for privacy)
 access_token = ""
 access_token_secret = ""
 consumer_key = ""
 consumer_secret = ""

 #This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
 class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

     def on_data(self, data):
         print data
         return True

     def on_error(self, status):
         print status

 if __name__ == '__main__':

     #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
     l = StdOutListener()
     auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
     auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
     stream = Stream(auth, l)

#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
     stream.filter(track=['abc']) # <= here is the language filter issue
```

Comment: By the error in screenshot there is no keyword agrument with language/lan in it. Please check the documentation.

Comment: Hi imagin,  the official document says "For example, connecting with language=en will only stream Tweets detected to be in the English language."  But it never works.  That is why I post here.

Comment: You are using any python package? Post some more code about it.

Comment: Just add the whole code.  The issue happens in the last line of the code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name of the keyword for the `filter()` function is actually `languages` (note the `s` on the end.) So, your last line should look like this:

```
stream.filter(track=['abc'], languages=['en'])
```