# python remove tweet texts like '\xe2\x80\x98'

Tags: regex, python-2.7, tweets

First time doing a text mining project.

1. After tokenized and count the most frequent words, there are many results such as

   *format: `("string", frequency)`*

   ```
   ('\xe2\x80\x98', 3476)
   ('\xed\xa0\xbd', 2268)
   ```

   May I know if there is a special meaning for this \xed,\xe0,or \whatever?  I google it but cannot find anything. :?
2. May I know if there is any clean python regular expression way to include any tweets starting with `\` into the unwanted word (including into the "stop" list in the following script)?

Here is the script which I make a stop word list to remove unwanted words:

```
# python 2.7, nltk 3.1

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import string

punctuation = list(string.punctuation)

# Extra terms to remove
# rt, RT (retweet), via (retweet)

stop = stopwords.words('english') + punctuation + ['rt', 'via'] # Unwanted word list

for line in tweets_file:

    try:

        tweet= json.loads(line)

        terms_stops = [term for term in preprocess(tweet['text']) if term not in stop]

        terms_stops_utf=[x.encode('utf-8') for x in terms_stops]
```

Comment: those are byte strings that your editor/system isn't able to display. Could be some foreign character/ foreign language punctuation which the ascii codec cannot encode

Comment: Thanks! Now we know what it is.  Is there any clean way to remove them? I have another post: the language filter in the twitter streaming API doesn't really work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404682/python-2-7-twitter-streaming-api-language-filter?noredirect=1#comment54602602_33404682 So I need to figure out a way to remove these byte strings

Comment: Update: terms_stops_utf=[x.encode('utf-8') for x in terms_stops if not x.startswith("\\x")] orterms_stops_utf=[x.encode('utf-8') for x in terms_stops if not x.startswith("\x")] could be a solution, but no luck.  Still try to figure it out

Comment: It's already encoded. Try decoding it. The whole string.

Comment: Good point!  I find a solution but it seems some other normal words will be removed/ignored.  "terms_stops_utf=[x.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf','ignore') for x in terms_stops]"